# how to input txt file in eclipse if i already have skeleton code to read/iterate though these files?

Tags: java, eclipse

My teacher already gave us a skeleton code to iterate through **.txt** files, but I am not quite sure how to tell **Eclipse** (my IDE) which one to use?

I moved the sample .txt file into the same **src** folder, and I made sure that the names were exactly the same, but I am getting an error message saying that the file I specified can't be found.

I also tried copying and pasting all the text into the **run configuration** (in the main argument box)... I think it's the equivalent of the command line in MS Windows.

Here's the piece of code I'm referring to:

```
public class FileCharIterator implements Iterator<String> {

    protected FileInputStream input;
    private String inputFileName;
    private int nextChar;

    public FileCharIterator(String inputFileName) {
        try {
            input = new FileInputStream(inputFileName);
            nextChar = input.read();
            this.inputFileName = inputFileName;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.printf("No such file: %s\n", inputFileName);
            System.exit(1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.printf("IOException while reading from file %s\n",
                    inputFileName);
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return nextChar != -1;
    }

    @Override
    public String next() {
        if (this.nextChar == -1) {
            return "";
        } else {
            Byte b = (byte) this.nextChar;
            String toRtn = String.format("%8s",
                    Integer.toBinaryString(b & 0xFF)).replace(' ', '0');
            try {
                this.nextChar = this.input.read();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.printf(
                        "IOException while reading in from file %s\n",
                        this.inputFileName);
            }
            return toRtn;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void remove() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
                "FileCharIterator does not delete from files.");
    }
}
```

I am very sure that the skeleton code works, and that the error happens because I am not sending commands correctly. If you could explain to me what I am doing that wrong I will be very grateful.
Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: We can't see your skeleton code, so we have no idea how it works..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy text File into class Path.(into the project folder , not to src folder)